# Python-telegram-bot alternative for buttons

Tags: telegram

I'm trying to make a casino bot on telegram and I wanted to know if I can use some sort of bar to choose how much the user will bet, I was thinking of using a bar like this one: [The bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1617.png).
As I always see people using inline keyboards, never saw anything like it and some research without finding anything my only hope is to ask here.
If I can't use this selection bar is there something else that I can use instead of buttons?

Comment: There is no slider-selection in the native TG apps. You could use the inline mode to present a scrollable list of possible values. Alternatively, you can use Telegrams webapps concept, which would allow to use such a slider selector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some pseudo-code to give you an idea for the first approach:
You'll have to hook this up with your bot's message handlers and possibly a database to keep track of individual user's states

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup

def create_keyboard(current_value):
    keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton("-10", callback_data=f"decrement_10"),
         InlineKeyboardButton("-1", callback_data=f"decrement_1"),
         InlineKeyboardButton(f"Current Bet: {current_value}", callback_data="none"),
         InlineKeyboardButton("+1", callback_data=f"increment_1"),
         InlineKeyboardButton("+10", callback_data=f"increment_10")],
    ]
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

def button(update, context):
    query = update.callback_query
    current_value = get_current_value_somehow()  # Implement this function

    if "increment" in query.data:
        amount = int(query.data.split("_")[1])
        current_value += amount
    elif "decrement" in query.data:
        amount = int(query.data.split("_")[1])
        current_value -= amount
        if current_value < 0:
            current_value = 0

    query.edit_message_text(
        text=f"Choose your bet:",
        reply_markup=create_keyboard(current_value)
    )
```